# What algorithm does Linq GroupBy use?

Tags: c#, algorithm

Linq GroupBy seems super performant, so I'm wondering what kind of algorithm it uses under the covers.

Comment: "Super performant" in comparison to what?

Comment: I imagine it uses something like the `ToLookup` extension for its work. In many ways it's like a dictionary except with multiple values rather than a single value.

Comment: It seems to be able to somehow lazy evaluate the groupings, which doesn't even seem possible.

Comment: I'm refraining from posting this as answer because it feels like stealing but read http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-21-groupby.aspx

Comment: @sircodesalot, yes, that's the primary difference between ILookup and GroupBy (GroupBy is lazy, although I'd venture that the source sequence will need to be entirely consumed work correctly). Why not take a peek at the code? DotPeek is quite handy for this. http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Comment: In fact, I just took a look. GroupBy gives you a `GroupedEnumerable`. Asking for its enumerator causes a Lookup to be built (in a non-lazy fashion).

Comment: Just look at the source code in the Reference Source, net\fx\src\Core\System\Linq\Enumerable.cs

Comment: Actually this question is somewhat meaningless. Group by is really just another Linq expression which gets implemented by whatever Linq provider you are using. All of the cases the above replies show are for Linq to objects. Linq to Entities obviously uses SQL and PLinq uses another algo also.

Comment: Jon Skeet's article on msmvps.com was moved to https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-21-groupby/